# Dex error when trying to build ionic Android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying to build an ionic app for Android but when I run

```
ionic cordova run android
```

I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files
```

Trying to run ./gradlew clean gets me

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue but it was resolved. Thanks to information from @notlose at this link https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android/issues/32

**Solution:**
just remove both *'build'* folder in */android* and */android/app*
and build again with
'*react-native run-android*' for react-native
'*ionic cordova run android*' for ionic

Comment: Confirmed as the solution for me at least.